# Проверить каждый член коллекции целых чисел (вводимых пользователем) на принадлежность к string или int

Tags: c#, строки, int

Проблема на первый взгляд была проста, но оказалась сложнее. Помогите пж не могу понять как решить.

Нужно заполнить коллекцию целых чисел (15) данными вводимыми пользователем, и при этом проверить принадлежит ли каждый из них к `int` или к `string`.

- В случае если все данные `int` вывести коллекцию.
- В случае если данные типа `string`, оповестить в консоль об ошибке.

Если непонятно объяснил то задание в видео:
(Циклы C# (for, foreach, while) - Учим Шарп #7)(1:01:52)

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не так поняли задачу и то, что требуется. Вот подумайте сами, зачем вам в стакан наливать сразу воду, газировку и сок, если можно их отфильтровать до наливания, а не фильтровать потом эту жидкость на составляющие? Также и тут, зачем вам коллекция, содержащая в себе разные значения, если можно сразу просить пользователя ввести число (`if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value)) { ... }`)?

Comment: Спасибо большое! И вправду попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример, изучайте. Здесь и `while` и `for`, только `foreach` я заменил на `string.Join`. И условия и интерполяция строк, и `int` и `int[]` массив.

Выполните код пошагово в режиме отладки, проверяйте значения переменных, смотрите как работает. Пробуйте многократно вводить не числа или дробные числа.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите количество чисел n от 1 до 15: ");
    int n;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n) || n < 1 || n > 15)
    {
        Console.Write("Некорректный ввод, введите n от 1 до 15: ");
    }

    int[] a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write($"Введите a[{i}]: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a[i]))
        {
            Console.Write($"Не удалось распознать число, введите a[{i}]: ");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели {n} чисел:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```